# Edujugon Push Notification

Tags: android, laravel, android-push-notification

i am trying Edujugon Push Notification laravel; all configuration be correct.
my push notification code is

$push = new PushNotification('fcm');

```
    $push->setMessage([
    'notification' => [
            'title'=>'This is the title',
            'body'=>'This is the message',
            'sound' => 'default'
            ],
    'data' => [
            'extraPayLoad1' => 'value1',
            'extraPayLoad2' => 'value2'
            ]
    ])        
    ->setApiKey('AAAAv7w78uY:APA91bF73GY1AcZvBh84K2matRxFwWB0VQysqlDzsLBtrmVRbRN0e6T2Lxasiv-sNfWaNQwqgltTaiaL0rZVC5TKzwfZRgrxb30B4jkl2bzJ9DViZsbGVdQMNOJ78FtOfwcUCgvUj_XC7jLdargjnfKQAD0ecbWMlA')
    ->setDevicesToken('fj6Sx3zYjhM:APA91bE3cas4LPX-T9jJ-7YgKrMIYOiD5Brjf9AgqvCUsSN7OygZEX3qhQ1F4RxCZfsvSCHNV9gq15NL26k62KBuWqpX4G9nrSQHT3ddabCTRwinqbmpt53gtdCgakaW5LvSxA1t1-iiZS8at8pW7W9o5Gyv2mBSEw');
    $push = $push->send();
```

Comment: my response cose is

Comment: feedback response                     stdClass Object ( [multicast_id] => -1 [success] => 1 [failure] => 0 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message_id] => fake_message_id ) ) )

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: push notification could not be send on my mobile

Comment: is device token and api key are correct? Please check that also

Comment: ya its correct ,i have checked many time

Comment: please check setmessage array[]   for android fcm cloud message is correct or not??

Comment: feedback also be stdClass Object ( [multicast_id] => -1 [success] => 1 [failure] => 0 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message_id] => fake_message_id ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://packagist.org/packages/edujugon/push-notification

```
$push->setMessage([
    'notification' => [
            'title'=>'This is the title',
            'body'=>'This is the message',
            'sound' => 'default'
            ],
    'data' => [
            'extraPayLoad1' => 'value1',
            'extraPayLoad2' => 'value2'
            ]
    ])
    ->setApiKey('Server-API-Key')
    ->setDevicesToken(['deviceToken1','deviceToken2','deviceToken3'...]);
```

Comment: i have also try this  but not fix

Answer (score 0):

used this package [LARAVEL-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) EASY TO USED

Comment: please tell me about $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);  in this plugin.

Comment: $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20) .
This funcation specifies how long the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline.

Answer (score 0):

I have also integrated push notification in laravel using below code, hope it helps you :

```
function sendPushNotification($fcm_token, $title, $message, $id="") {  
        $push_notification_key = Config::get('settings.PUSH_NOTIFICATION_KEY');    
        $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";            
        $header = array("authorization: key=" . $push_notification_key . "",
            "content-type: application/json"
        );    

        $postdata = '{
            "to" : "' . $fcm_token . '",
                "notification" : {
                    "title":"' . $title . '",
                    "text" : "' . $message . '"
                },
            "data" : {
                "id" : "'.$id.'",
                "title":"' . $title . '",
                "description" : "' . $message . '",
                "text" : "' . $message . '",
                "is_read": 0
              }
        }';

        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 120;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        // Get URL content
        $result = curl_exec($ch);    
        // close handle to release resources
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it is better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers tend to be less useful in the long run. See [How do I write a good answer?
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some more info.